# convert fingerprint txt data with python

Tags: python, file, type-conversion, txt

I m newbie python
A device (Personnel Continuity Control System (PCCS)) data.txt

```
001,00025,1 2021/09/28 08:18:38 000
001,00012,1 2021/09/28 08:18:42 000
001,00027,1 2021/09/28 08:18:45 000
001,00011,1 2021/09/28 08:18:47 000
001,00025,1 2021/09/28 18:19:14 000
001,00012,1 2021/09/28 18:29:04 000
001,00027,1 2021/09/29 07:59:35 000
001,00025,1 2021/09/29 08:10:00 000
001,00011,1 2021/09/29 08:20:11 000
001,00027,1 2021/09/29 18:23:14 000
001,00025,1 2021/09/29 18:27:05 000
001,00012,1 2021/09/29 18:27:58 000
```

---

my ERP program request
personel;join date and time;quit date and time like;

```
025;28.09.2021 08:18:38;28.09.2021 18:19:14
```

---

```
#import pandas as pd
import datetime
        
file =open("data.txt","r",encoding='utf-8')

users   = []
dates    = []
hours     = []
    
for i in file:
    year =int(i[12:16])
    mount  = int(i[17:19])
    day = int(i[20:22])
    hour = int(i[23:25])
    minute =int(i[26:28])
    second = int(i[29:31])
    
    date1 = datetime.date(year,mount,day)#.strftime("%d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%S")
    hour1 = datetime.time(hour,minute,second)#.strftime("%H:%M:%S")

    
    user =i[6:9]
    

    # if user == "025":
    #     if date1 == datetime.date(2021,9,28):
    #       cannot use min - max or if segment <> hour1
    
    users.append(f'{user}')
    dates.append(f'{date1}')
    hours.append(f'{hour1}')
```

I want to print the same users and the same dates as input and output, on the same line, to a different file.

how can I do it?

```
025;28.09.2021 08:18:38;28.09.2021 18:19:14
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that you want to copy some data from one file to another, in which case i would use

```
with open("filepath", "rb") as file: # open file
    frl = file.readlines() # read it's contents, returns list
    with open("filepath2", "wb") as file2: # open save file
        file2.write(b''.join(frl)) # save it into the new file (copying)
```

x.join takes a list and combines each element with the string, x
if you want to only copy certain parts you can use frl.index(string) which returns the index of the item you are searching for